# how can I concatenate string plus a value in an if statement inside an append in jquery using grave accent for html?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, append

This is my code, and it works!, but I tried to concatenate a dollar symbol before the value['precio] but doesn´t work.

```
var servicios_carrito = ` <li class="header-cart-item flex-w flex-t m-b-12">
                                                {{-- Imagen de Servicio --}}
                                                <div class="header-cart-item-img">
                                                <img src=" ` + value['foto_1'] + ` " class="rounded" alt="IMG">
                                                </div>
                                                {{-- Nombre de Servicio --}}
                                                <div class="header-cart-item-txt p-t-8">
                                                    <a href="#" class="header-cart-item-name m-b-18 hov-cl1 trans-04">
                                                    ` + value['titulo'] + `
                                                    </a>
                                                    {{-- Precio de Servicio --}}
                                                    <span class="header-cart-item-info">
                                                        $
                                                    ` + (value['precio'] != null ? + '$' + value['precio'] : 'Precio a convenir' ) +`
                                                    </span>
                                                </div>
                                            </li>
                                            <hr>
                                            `;
                    $('#servicios_carrito').append(servicios_carrito);
```

In the navigator view when I put + '$' +   before value, shows me "NaN"

Comment: There is a dollar symbol before the if statement, but the symbol must be before the value[precio]

Comment: I tired with $$ and doesn´t work, may be inside the if statement jquery only allows to print one value. I need to show $ only when the condition is true.

Comment: why you don't use a pipe?, it is better and permit to have more control